# Ошибка 'import-im6.q16: not authorized `keyboard' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037.'

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/manager/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    events = keyboard.record('esc')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keyboard/__init__.py", line 1041, in record
    start_recording()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keyboard/__init__.py", line 1016, in start_recording
    _recording = (recorded_events_queue, hook(recorded_events_queue.put))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keyboard/__init__.py", line 461, in hook
    append(callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keyboard/_generic.py", line 67, in add_handler
    self.start_if_necessary()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keyboard/_generic.py", line 35, in start_if_necessary
    self.init()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keyboard/__init__.py", line 196, in init
    _os_keyboard.init()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keyboard/_nixkeyboard.py", line 113, in init
    build_device()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keyboard/_nixkeyboard.py", line 109, in build_device
    ensure_root()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keyboard/_nixcommon.py", line 174, in ensure_root
    raise ImportError('You must be root to use this library on linux.')
ImportError: You must be root to use this library on linux.
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Сам код небольшой, при нажатии на ESC - пишет g

```
import keyboard
events = keyboard.record('esc')
keyboard.play(events)
keyboard.send('g')
```

Насчет нехватки прав в нете ничего не нашел.
Но самое интересное, что ошибки выскакивают только на Linux, на домашней машине проблем нет и всё работает. Тот же PyCharm и та же версия..

*Правка.
Пробовал открывать питон файл с скриптом, появляется другой курсор и при нажатии на что либо вот эта ошибка*

```
import-im6.q16: not authorized `keyboard' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037.
./bot.py: строка 7: синтаксическая ошибка рядом с неожиданным маркером «(»
./bot.py: строка 7: `events = keyboard.record('esc')'
```

Comment: Почему бы просто не запустить питон с скриптом под sudo?

Comment: т.е. как обычный скрипт? дать права на исполнение и запустить?

Comment: да, так и сделайте

Comment: @gil9red попробовал, меняется курсор на выделение и вот что пишет
`import-im6.q16: not authorized keyboard @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037.
./bot.py: строка 7: синтаксическая ошибка рядом с неожиданным маркером «"g"»
./bot.py: строка 7: keyboard.send("g")`

Comment: Синтаксическая ошибка... странно... Добавьте в вопрос полный стек ошибки. У вас ведь код сейчас такой же как в вопросе?

Comment: @gil9red да, код такой же.

Comment: А как вы запускаете файла и что находится в первых двух строках файла (я про шебанг строку)

Comment: @gil9red Запускаю из терминала через `./bot.py`
Вот первые 4 строчки 

`# This is a sample Python script.
# Press Shift+F10 to execute it or replace it with your code.
# Press Double Shift to search everywhere for classes, files, tool windows, actions, and settings.
# !/usr/bin/python`

Comment: Не знаю насчет строк комментарий, влиляют ли они на что ли... Но с `# !/usr/bin/python` есть вопрос. У вас по этому пути питон версии 3 находится? Если нет, то укажите путь к третьему питону, типа `#!/usr/bin/python3`

Comment: @gil9red если все правильно понял, то да, там, но я подправил на всякий случай

Answer (score 0):

Вам в ошибке пишет "ImportError: You must be root to use this library on linux.".
То есть вам надо писать sudo python3 ваш_файл.py

Comment: А можно сделать так, чтобы файл исполнялся в самом PyCharm (то есть добавить рут права) как и положено в других средах, а не заходить в терминал?

Comment: Честно говоря не знаю. Сам я запускал через терминал. Но посмотрите настройки PyCharm'а. Вроде бы такого нету

Comment: Вы можете в ярлыке запуска PyCharm запускать его от root, если он это позволяет